# How to extend the width of a button using SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swiftui, xcode11

I cannot figure out how to change the width of buttons in SwiftUI.

I have already attempted:
using .frame(minWidth: 0, maxWidth: .infinity),
using Spacer() around the button and navigationlink,
using frame on the Text field and padding on the button, look through the documentation, as well as a few other things I found while just searching online. However nothing changes the buttons width whatsoever.

```
NavigationLink(destination: Home(), isActive: self.$isActive) { Text("") }
Button(action: { self.isActive = true }) { LoginBtn() }

struct LoginBtn: View {
    var body: some View {
        Text("Login")
            .fontWeight(.bold)
            .padding()
            .foregroundColor(Color.white)
            .background(Color.orange)
            .cornerRadius(5.0)
    }
}
```

[Photo of current button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VC4iH.png)

I would like to have the button to extend to be similar to the width of the TextFields used. Again, I know there have been answers posted but for some reason I cannot get mine to work. Thanks!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Declare your own button style:

```
struct WideOrangeButton: ButtonStyle {

    func makeBody(configuration: Configuration) -> some View {
        configuration.label
            .padding()
            .frame(minWidth: 0,
                   maxWidth: .infinity)
            .foregroundColor(.white)
            .padding()
            .background( RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 5.0).fill(Color.orange)
        )
    }
}
```

and then use it like this:

```
Button(action: { self.isActive = true }) {
        Text("Login")
           .fontWeight(.bold)
    }   .buttonStyle(WideOrangeButton())
```

Answer (score 10):

I like this approach since it lets me use the default button style, but still results in a wider button.

```
Button(action: {
    // Whatever button action you want.
}, label: {
    Text("Okay")
        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
})
.buttonStyle(.automatic)
```