# Span two Buttons across HStack in SwiftUI (Big Sur)

Tags: macos, swiftui, macos-big-sur

I have a problem getting the correct alignment for two buttons (Cancel and OK) in a sheet using SwiftUI.

I want the two buttons to appear at the bottom of the sheet so that the two of them span the whole horizontal width of the sheet (minus padding).

I've found several answers (such as setting the `maxWidth` to `.infinity` or by [putting the text contend of a button in a separate `Text` view and surrounding it by `Spacer`s](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56471004/making-button-span-across-vstack)) but none of them seem to work for me. The only one that works somewhat is [by creating my own ButtonStyle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58458184/how-to-extend-the-width-of-a-button-using-swiftui). But then I have to recreate the whole default ButtonStyle (different for default button, for day and night mode,...)

The code I have now is:

```swift
    var body: some View {
        VStack() {

            ...

            HStack {
                Button("Cancel",action: {
                    isPresented.toggle()
                })
                .frame(minWidth: 0, maxWidth: .infinity)
                .padding()
                .keyboardShortcut(.cancelAction)
                .border(Color.red)
                Button("OK", action: {
                    isPresented.toggle()
                    let newServer = Server(name: name, url: url, port: port, autoConnect: autoConnect)
                    do {
                        try model.add(server: newServer)
                    } catch {
                        print("Could not add server.")
                    }
                })
                .frame(minWidth: 0, maxWidth: .infinity)
                .padding()
                .keyboardShortcut(.defaultAction)
                .border(Color.red)
            }
            .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
            .padding(.top, 20)
            .border(Color.blue)
        }
        .padding()
        .frame(minWidth: 300, maxWidth: 300)
    }
```

This results in the following sheet:

[image]

I would like both buttons to fill the area surrounded by the red border.

I'm kinda at a loss on what to try next!

Comment: This is SwiftUI DefaultButtonStyle, we cannot modify it, but we can use custom one. Next should be helpful https://stackoverflow.com/a/59290554/12299030.

Answer (score 0):

as the red borders show, the buttons do extend to fill the area.
To get the background gray as in the picture, you could use something like:

```
.background(Color(UIColor.systemGray4))
```

as the last modifier of each buttons.

Answer (score 0):

Default button style is rendered around provided label content, so possible solution is to calculate needed width for button label dynamically and apply it explicitly.

*Note: please also see my comment for alternate*

Demo prepared with Xcode 12.5 / macOS 11.3

[image]

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var cancelWidth = CGFloat.zero
    @State private var okWidth = CGFloat.zero

    var body: some View {
        VStack() {
            Text("Demo here!")
            HStack(spacing: 0) {
                Button(action: {
                }) { Text("Cancel").frame(width: cancelWidth) }
                .frame(minWidth: 0, maxWidth: .infinity)
                .background(GeometryReader {
                    Color.clear.preference(key: ViewWidthKey.self,
                          value: $0.frame(in: .local).size.width) })
                .onPreferenceChange(ViewWidthKey.self) { self.cancelWidth = $0 }
                .padding()
                .border(Color.red)
                .keyboardShortcut(.cancelAction)

                Button(action: {
                }) { Text("OK").frame(width: okWidth) }
                .frame(minWidth: 0, maxWidth: .infinity)
                .background(GeometryReader {
                    Color.clear.preference(key: ViewWidthKey.self,
                          value: $0.frame(in: .local).size.width) })
                .onPreferenceChange(ViewWidthKey.self) { self.okWidth = $0 }
                .padding()
                .keyboardShortcut(.defaultAction)
                .border(Color.red)
            }
            .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
            .padding(.top, 20)
            .border(Color.blue)
        }
        .padding()
        .frame(minWidth: 300, maxWidth: 300)
    }
}

struct ViewWidthKey: PreferenceKey {
    typealias Value = CGFloat
    static var defaultValue: CGFloat { 0 }
    static func reduce(value: inout Value, nextValue: () -> Value) {
        value = value + nextValue()
    }
}
```